# Hacer peticiones de confirmacion al crear ordenes NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

estoy tratando de crear unas notificaciones una vez que se creen una orden, este es el codigo

```
async createOrder(payload) {
// create order 
return await this.httpService.axiosRef
  .post(`${this.api}/orders`, payload, {
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/json',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      authorization: `Bearer xxxxxx`
      )}`,
    },
  })
  .then((response) => response.data);
```

}

lo que necesito hacer es enviar un dato que viene en el payload, a un endopint para confirmarlo, pero no se como encolarlo, o hacer un metodo seguido para que pueda lograrse, digamos que ocupo enviar `payload.dato` a `google.com/success` para que esto suceda, esta funcion forma parte de una promesa en un controlador

Comment: dejame entender , necesitas enviar el token a otro end point?

Comment: Solo ocupo enviar un fragmento del payload a otro endpoint, pero necesito que se hagan las 2 peticiones, pero cuando las hago una de ellas no se hace

Comment: ya te entiendo , tienes esa funcion en el mismo servicio ? o lo tienes en otro servicio ?, si lo tienes en el mismo servicio , solo deberias llamar a la funcion que te hace la peticion despues del await con el this.enviarNotificacion(data : any). y luego respondes al controlador.